# Adding an AuthorizationHandler via config

Tags: web-config, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

In WCF, you can add an authorization policy through the web.config by using the `serviceAuthorization` node in a service behavior.  Is there a way to include an `AuthorizationHandler` in .NET Core WebAPI via config?

To be clear, I'm trying to replace this line in `Startup.cs` with something in the web.config:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MyAuthorizationHandler>();
```

Comment: My first question would be why do you believe you need to do that. I ask this to clarify that this is not an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as there is not much context to work with from the limited details of the post in its current state.

Comment: @Nkosi:  I'm working on creating an authorization component that can be dropped into multiple services in our organization.  Being able to do so in the config (and being able to remove it from the config) is a desired behavior, as that's how our current one for WCF works.

Comment: Makes sense. Now the idea playing around in my head is to update the configuration in settings json file, but would require some custom code to use that config, as well as having to stop and restart host, but not recompile.

Comment: @Nkosi:  No way to do it in the web.config, where the IIS tie-in is set up?

Comment: Nope. web.config is only used for IIS specific config. Because of .net-core's cross platform nature they ditched coupling to web config for application configuration.

Comment: @Nkosi:  Thanks!  Sounds like it's better to just make the component be added in Startup and leave it at that.

Comment: Yes. that is the route to take. But like I said before. startup is your entry point but you can have some settings in the json file and have your code add the config based on that. My thinking is that it would save having to recompile every time you want to add something.

Comment: @Nkosi:  Thanks.  If you add that as an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*web.config* is only used for IIS specific config. Because of .net-core's cross platform nature they ditched coupling to web config for application configuration.

> A *web.config* file is required when hosting the app in IIS or IIS Express. Settings in *web.config* enable the ASP.NET Core Module to launch the app and configure other IIS settings and modules.

Reference [Configure an ASP.NET Core App: The web.config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?tabs=basicconfiguration#the-webconfig-file)

*Startup* is your entry point into the application where you can have some settings in the json file and have your code add/update the configuration based on that.

My thinking is that it would save having to recompile every time you want to add something because configuration options allows you to [Reload configuration data with IOptionsSnapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options#reload-configuration-data-with-ioptionssnapshot)
*Requires ASP.NET Core 1.1 or later.*

> `IOptionsSnapshot` supports reloading options with minimal processing overhead. In ASP.NET Core 1.1, `IOptionsSnapshot` is a snapshot of `IOptionsMonitor<TOptions>` and updates automatically whenever the monitor triggers changes based on the data source changing. In ASP.NET Core 2.0 and later, options are computed once per request when accessed and cached for the lifetime of the request.

Your authorization handler(s) would depend on the options and perform its function based on the configurations provided.